# ASP DropDownList in IE10 doesn't seem to obey Width?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-10

I've got some dropdown lists inside a table, inside a container div with a fixed width.

In older versions of IE, and the other main browsers, it works how I need it to: the list's entry line obeys the width and stays inside the container. The dropdown part expands to contain the longest entry within it, and sits above the container, going beyond the edge as necessary.

In IE10 it's sizing the entry line to the maximum width of the list contents, disregarding the width setting, and therefore causing the table to expand out of the container div.

Am I doing something dumb, or is it a bug in IE10?
Is there any way of fixing this?

Example code...

```
    <div class="container roundedCornersSmall shadow" style="float: left; width: 330px;
padding-left: 20px;">
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td>
              <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTeam" Text="Team" SkinID="FormLabels" />
           </td>
           <td>
              <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drpTeams" Width="225px" Columns="30"/>
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can you include a demo where we can run your code?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's an intranet site.  And I don't think there's an equivalent of JsFiddle for ASP?